# Other jquery effect disfunction when I want to load JQUERY & JQUERY-UI on admin page

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui, google-maps

Currently I'm doing my project which is I'm creating an option page that have google map that allow user to point the marker and allow them to save the location. This google map use auto complete jquery-ui function.

Therefore i load in my function.php like this:

```
//JQuery//

function re_init_jQuery() {

    wp_deregister_script('jquery'); 
    wp_register_script('jquery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

}
add_action('init', re_init_jQuery);

//JQUERY UI//

function re_init_jQuery_ui() {

    wp_deregister_script('jquery-ui');
    wp_register_script('jquery-ui', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui');

}
add_action('init', 're_init_jQuery_ui');
```

But this make other jquery effect like dragable widget, quick edit that use default jquery disfunction.

When I turn off the loading step above, my google map also dissappeared.

Anyone could help me for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It means that you've already have jQuery on this page.

Do you add the whole jQuery-ui script?

So, you have to add only jquery-ui-autocomplete file. [Here](http://jqueryui.com/download) You can deselect all checkboxes and then check up only autocomplete function. And download your custom jquery-ui build